# Template helper not updating after session.set

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code needs to change the value of the `headerLabel` based on `Session.get('headerLabel')`, which when gets set in a different client side file, it does not update the template display.

Why and how can I fix it? Thanks

```js
// client/header.js
Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function () {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    if (!userId) {
      Session.set('headerLabel', 'Please login');
    } else {
      Meteor.subscribe('headerLabel');
      let label = HeaderLabelCol.findOne({userId: userId}).headerLabel;
      Session.set('headerLabel', label);
    }
    return {headerLabel: Session.get('headerLabel')};
  }
});

// client/lib.js
utility = (function () {
  return {
    toast: function (headerMsg) {
      const temp = Session.get('headerLabel');
      Session.set('headerLabel', headerMsg);
      setTimeout(() => {Session.set('headerLabel', temp)}, 2000);
    }
  }
}());
```

```html
<template name="header">
  <header>
    <h1 class="main-menu">
      <button class="mainMenu" type="button">&#9776;</button>
    </h1>
    <h3>
      <label class="header-label">
        {{headerLabel.headerLabel}}
      </label>
    </h3>
    <h1>
      <button class="subMenu" type="button">&#8942;</button>
    </h1>
  </header>
</template>
```

And this gets invoked from some other file in the client side 
`utility.toast('Wrong entries');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper functions are supposed to only fetch the data needed for your template, they should never manipulate the state of your app. Particularly, the `Meteor.subscribe` you call creates a new subscription handle each time the template is rerendered. This is a serious leak.

Instead you should move your logic code to `onCreated`, `onRendered` and `onDestroyed` methods.

```
Template.header.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe('headerLabel');
  this.autorun(function() {
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    if (userId) {
      let label = HeaderLabelCol.findOne({userId: userId}).headerLabel;
      Session.set('headerLabel', label);
    } else {
      Session.set('headerLabel', 'Please login');
    }
  });
});

Template.header.helpers({
  headerLabel: function () {
    return Session.get('headerLabel');
  },
});
```